# Actualizar los datos de una colleccion en laravel

Tags: laravel, orm

desde hace semanas tengo un problema con la vista de actualizar (y los metodos edit/update). Y es lo siguiente:

Si tengo un Examen este tiene sus propias Preguntas

```
Examen1
     -> Pregunta 1
     -> Pregunta 2
     -> Pregunta 3

Examen2
     -> Pregunta 4
     -> Pregunta 5
     -> Pregunta 6

Examen N
     -> Pregunta N
     -> Pregunta N+1
     -> Pregunta N+1
```

El detalle radica en que, cuando entro a cualquier Examen (en este caso `Examen 2`) e intento editar cualquier pregunta, por ejemplo `Pregunta 4`. Lo que obtengo es la vista `edit.blade.php` con los datos de la primera pregunta del primer examen, es decir, me filtra así:

```
Examen1
     -> Pregunta 1
```

Adjunto mi `controller`

```
public function edit($id){
        $exams = Exam::find($id);
        $questions = Question::find($id);
        $category = Category::all();

        return view('question.edit', compact('exams', 'questions', 'category'));
    }

    public function update(QuestionUpdateRequest $request, $id){
        $exams = Exam::find($id);
        $questions = Question::find($id);
        $questions->description = $request->get('description');
        $questions->iframe = $request->get('iframe');
        $questions->image = $request->get('image');

        $questions->exam_id = $request->get('exam_id');
        $questions->category_id = $request->get('category_id');
        $questions->save();
        return redirect()->route('question.index', $questions->exam_id);
    }
```

el `index.blade.php`

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Descripcion</th>
            <th>Categoria</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($exams->questions as $question)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$question->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$question->description}}</a></td>
            <td>{{$question->category->name}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a>
                <a href="{{ route('questions.edit', [ $exams->id, $question->id ]) }}"
                   class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Cuando ejecuto el `dd()` me arroja esto:

```
App\Question {#1288 ▼
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "questions"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 9
    "exam_id" => 1
    "category_id" => 2
    "description" => "iwqueo"
    "iframe" => "wpqueoiq"
    "image" => null
    "order" => null
    "created_at" => "2020-08-19 04:26:13"
    "updated_at" => "2020-08-19 04:26:13"
  ]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
}
```

Y mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo filtrar en el edit para que me muestre la pregunta que intento editar?

**EDIT 1**

Agrego el como tengo las rutas de mi proyecto.

En mi archivo web, uso

```php
Route::resource('/exams/{exam}/questions', 'Backend\QuestionController');
```

Esto me genera las siguientes rutas en automatico...

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/create                           | exams.create       | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ExamController@create                     | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}                           | exams.show         | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ExamController@show                       | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | PUT|PATCH | exams/{exam}                           | exams.update       | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ExamController@update                     | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | DELETE    | exams/{exam}                           | exams.destroy      | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ExamController@destroy                    | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/edit                      | exams.edit         | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ExamController@edit                       | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST      | exams/{exam}/questions                 | questions.store    | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\QuestionController@store                  | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions                 | questions.index    | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\QuestionController@index                  | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/create          | questions.create   | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\QuestionController@create                 | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}      | questions.show     | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\QuestionController@show                   | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | PUT|PATCH | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}      | questions.update   | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\QuestionController@update                 | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | DELETE    | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}      | questions.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\QuestionController@destroy                | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/edit | questions.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\QuestionController@edit                   | web        |
|        |           |                                        |                    |                                                                        | auth       |
```

Comment: En tu función de `edit`, pregunta y examen, en ambos buscas con el mismo `id`?

Comment: Si, segun tengo entendido que puedes usar el `$edit` para ambos, ¿no?

Comment: Le pasas dos parámetros en tu `route(, [exam->id, question->id])`, pero en tu función `edit` sólo hay un parámetro. Me estoy equivocando?

Comment: No, no te equivocas. Lo agregue de esa manera, por la vista. Ya que `$exams->question` lo necesitaba asi. Sino me generaba un error que no obtenia las propiedades. ¿o a que te refieres? Siento que me fui por la tangente.

Comment: Podrías mostrar tu ruta de editar, por favor?

Comment: Listo, ya he agregado las rutas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112221/discussion-between-l-flor-and-edgar-gc).

Comment: Claro,  ya estoy en el chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente tu error se debe a que tu ruta requiere dos parámetros, pero en tu controlador sólo recibes un parámetro, tal y como la documentación lo muestra [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-parameters), tu método `edit`, debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
public function edit($examId, $questionId){
    $exams = Exam::find($examId);
    $questions = Question::find($questionId);
    $category = Category::all();

    return view('question.edit', compact('exams', 'questions', 'category'));
}
```

Analogamente, tu método `update` debe sufrir el mismo cambio, quedando de la misma manera:

```
public function update(QuestionUpdateRequest $request, $examId, $questionId){
    $exams = Exam::find($examId);
    $questions = Question::find($questionId);
    ...
}
```

---

Además, he notado que tenías una validación para el campo `exam_id`, el cuál ya viaja en la URL. Esto te ocasianaba un error HTTP `422`. Dado que el parámetro `$examId` viaja en la URL, éste no es validado mediante el `Request`. Si quieres validarlo, debes agregarlo al request, una manera de hacerlo es sobreescribiendo el método `all()` en tu `QuestionUpdateRequest`:

```
// ruta: exams/{exam}/questions/{question}
public function all($keys = null)
{
    $data = parent::all();
    $data['exam_id'] = $this->route('exam');
    return $data;
}
```